# Newly installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS freezes for 1-2 seconds a few times per hour

Tags: 22.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 on a Dell Latitude 5330 with Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2) and kernel 5.19.0-35-generic.

The mouse, sound, and keyboard freeze for a few seconds every 10-15 minutes.

I followed [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/zhhph3/ubuntu_2204_is_freezing_itself/) and tried disabling "Wayland" using this post on [linuxconfig.org](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop) but it doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: Start by looking with the top command in a terminal to monitor if you have a process taking a lot of CPU